# jQuery Submit is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I used modal of bootstrap and when i click **Add Changes** button, nothing happens.. :(

Script in head:

```
<script>
$("addBtn").click(function() {
    $("programFormDropDown").submit(function(event) {           
    });
});
</script>
```

My modal in body:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm your change</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">Are you sure you need to add these ?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button id="addBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Add changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

and my form in same body

```
<form id="programFormDropDown" action="../hDashBoard/project">
```

.....

can you give some idea?

Comment: are you using Mootools?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have forgoten a `#` in your selectors, **unless you are using Mootools** which gets the ID with `$('id')` try this:

```
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
   ^
    $("#programFormDropDown").submit(function(event) { 
       ^          
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the '#' reference from your selector.

```
<script>
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
    $("#programFormDropDown").submit(function(event) {           
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have miss `#` in two selector jquery

try this:

```
$("#addBtn").click(function() {
    $("#programFormDropDown").submit(function(event) {           
    });
});
```

instead of this:

```
$("addBtn").click(function() {
    $("programFormDropDown").submit(function(event) {           
    });
});
```

Comment: Why downovted? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not looking for ajax submit, in that case change the button type to submit like

```
<button id="addBtn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add changes</button>
```

if you want to use script

```
/add script in dom ready handler
jQuery(function () {
    //use id selectors - # in front of id
    $("#addBtn").click(function () {
        //call the dom elements submit method
        $("#programFormDropDown")[0].submit();
    });
})
```